# ajax возвращает ответ с информацией, которая не должна быть доступна на клиенте, есть ли какое то промежуточное хранилище?

Tags: ajax

ajax возвращает ответ с информацией, которая не должна быть доступна на клиенте, есть ли какое то промежуточное хранилище? То есть ответ аякса должен в следующем аяксе отправляться на сервер, но чтобы она была не доступна в открытом виде

Answer (score 1):

То, что браузер получил ответ от сервера - это уже "в открытом виде". Если считать иначе - то будут проблемы. А промежуточными могут быть операционка например или антивирус или прочие программы.

Comment: То есть, предполагаю, что нужно записывать на стороне сервера, в файле  php ,куда отправляется ajax  запрос, а в ответе выводить успешно записано на сервере, или повтороить запрос, обратиться к администратору сайта и т д?